# How to create an "empty" session in Django?

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

How can I create a session in Django, but without setting any specific variable?

I just need to send the session cookie to the client.

Comment: What's the benefit of setting the session cookie without any data in the corresponding session?

Comment: The problem  is that I would like to start a session (and use variables) when I redirect the client to a page. Apparently, cookies cannot be installed in an HTTP redirect, so I need to set the cookie prior to the redirect response.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, Django won't create a session ID/key unless you modify the `request.session` dictionary in some way. The following little "hack" is already enough to create a session:

```
request.session[None] = None
```

The most generic place to put this snippet would be a class-based view's `dispatch()` method. You can create a mixin to make things reusable:

```
class EmptySessionMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.session[None] = None
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class MyView(EmptySessionMixin, View):
    pass
```

Comment: This breaks `django-debug-toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I simply did:

```
request.session.save()
```

to create an (real) empty session...